# Web Audio API properties and methods on existing context

Tags: javascript, audio

I'm trying to switch completely to the Web Audio API and skip the html `<audio>` element alltogether.

I need access to playbackrate and a few other properties, but I'm not quite getting it to work.

I have an audiocontext that I use to analyse the file...

```
function loadMusic(file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    reader.onload = function(evt) {
        audioContext.decodeAudioData(reader.result,
            function(buffer) {
                currentBuffer = buffer;
                displayBuffer(buffer);
            }, onDecodeError);
    }
}
```

That works fine with a file loaded through `<input type="file">`

Then I use this to play the file:

```
function playSound() {
    var audio = audioContext.createBufferSource();
    audio.buffer = currentBuffer;
    audio.connect(audioContext.destination);
    audio.start(0);
}
```

Which also works fine...but how do I access audio.currentTime, duration, gain etc? I'm confused about how the Web audioContext works I think.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That's way too broad for SO. You indeed seem to miss some fundamentals about webAudio API. I can't redirect you to good tutos, but search for it, it will help you. Start playing around and read the docs. For the duration, if you mean the one of the AudioBuffer data, then there is a `duration` property on it. For the currentTime, it's quite hard to tell, it will depend on the AudioBufferSourceNode playbackrate and the time it took to load your AB and the delay you set before starting playing your AB and maybe even sampleRates.For the gain, you are in control you can add gainNodes in your chain.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'll look at the docs again.